# How to filter out the coordinate information according to a text file provided using Python?

Tags: python, filtering

I would like to filter the file B according to file A. I know how to do it using fasta_remove.py but I can't find any useful resources on how to filter out coordinates information. I want to remove coordinates that exist both in File B and File A. Can anyone help me?

**File A.txt**

```
chr2    158727965   158727975
chr1    153653137   153653147
```

**File B.txt**

```
chr1    159141551   159141561
chr1    159209558   159209568
chr2    158727965   158727975
chr1    153653137   153653147
chr1    159825015   159825025
```

**Desired Output**

```
chr1    159141551   159141561
chr1    159209558   159209568
chr1    159825015   159825025
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```py
with open('FileA.txt', 'r') as a, open('FileB.txt', 'r') as b, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    chra, chrb = a.read().splitlines(), b.read().splitlines()
    to_remove = set(chra).intersection(set(chrb))
    for c in chra + chrb:
        if c not in to_remove:
            o.write(c + '\n')
```

Comment: @Xiong89 you're welcome! Please mark the question as solved!